# LISP command won't work in init.el but works in *scratch*

Tags: init-file

I've executed the following lines in my scratch buffer

```
(require 'expand-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'er/expand-region)
```

and everything worked without any problems, but if I add those same lines to my init.el file I just get the following error

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, expand-region
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you misplaced the code before a change to the `load-path`?

Comment: Assuming you installed `expand-region` via `package.el`, you should not need `(require 'expand-region)` which only slows down Emacs's startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed `expand-region` via melpa you can just remove `(require 'expand-region)` from your init file because `er/expand-region` is autoloaded.

A bit of background:

`global-set-key` does not access the function value of `'er/expand-region` so one can use `global-set-key` even if `'er/expand-region` is not yet defined.

When [`package-initialize` runs at the end of the initialization (by default)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html) or maybe in the users init file the function `er/expand-region` is registered as autoloaded.

Thus when the user opens a file in `LaTeX-mode` and inputs the key sequence bound to `er/expand-region` the package `expand-region` is automagically loaded and `er/expand-region` is defined on demand.

Comment: BTW, in Emacs-27. installed packages get activated *before* loading `~/.emacs` rather than after.

Comment: @Stefan I know. That is the reason for the early initialization stuff: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7yns85/emacs_adds_support_for_a_second_read_earlier_init/ (configuration that must run before the activation of packages) Nevertheless, **it is very good that you mention it here.**